# при компиляции кода python через консоль ничего не происходит при использование строк с end = ''

Tags: python

Недавно начал учить питон, столкнулся с проблемой: при компиляции кода python через консоль ничего не происходит при использование строк с end = '', но, при этом, если компилирую через IDE (в моем случае это pycharm) всё нормально. В чём проблема?

```
import time
for x in range(6):
    print('.', end = '')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Что значит ничего не происходит?

Comment: Возможно у вас какие-либо проблемы , потому что у меня данный код прекрасно функционирует

Comment: Не происходит вообще ничего, просто пустая консоль, а спустя 30-60 секунд она закрывается

Comment: @arteazuse Приведите, пожалуйста, команду, которой запускаете файл из консоли. *P.S.:* `python script.py`.

Comment: Также можно проверить директорию на наличие скомпилированных `*pyc` файлов (удалите их).

Answer (score 2):

Данные, которые бы печатаете могли застрять где-то в буфере.
Попробуйте `print(".", flush = True, end = '')`

Answer (score 0):

Sergei Kirjanov прав.

Вывод в консоль(или файл) содержится в буфере до символа \n.
У вас вместо него end = ''.

Аргумент flush для функции print() (по умолчанию False)гарантирует, что любой вывод идет по назначению.